# I can't figure out how to read and populate a cell with core data on MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, crud

I'm a new macOS programmer and I just want to populate an NStable with firstName and lastName values already saved with CoreData. My entity is "User" and attributes are "firstName" and "lastName".

```
import Cocoa
import CoreData
import AppKit

class UserViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
        

    var context = (NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    
    var items: [User]?
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        fetchPeople()

    }

    
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
            return users.count
        }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
            
       guard let userCell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "userCell"), owner: self) as? CustomTableCell else { return nil }
    
        let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "User", into: context)

        //I know this is the wrong function but I don't know how to read the CoreData and fill my cells. This returns nil values.

        
            return userCell
        }
    
    
    // MARK: CodeWithChris Example (for iOS)
    
    func fetchPeople(){
        do {
            self.items = try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.NSTableView.reloadData() // NSTableView does not have reloadData
            }
           
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH8-SW1

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a little unclear where you're keeping your list of users. You have `var items: [User]?`, but in other places you have `users`, which isn't declared in the code you posted. That looks like it's probably also an array of `User`. You probably only want one of these but there's no way to tell which one from your question.

You seem to be on the right track. You need to fetch some (or all) `User` objects so that you can display them in the table. Your `fetchPeople()` function is a good start, though you might want to expand it a little. Right now it fetches all `User`s, but in a random order. You could add code to make it fetch only some of them, or to sort them so they always have the same order. There are some other things you could do to fine-tune the performance.

Your `numberOfRows` method is *close* to right, but that's where the confusion between `items` and `users` comes in. You should return the number of `User` objects that the fetch request found. That's probably `self.items.count`, but since I don't know where `users` comes from, I can't be sure of that.

In `tableView(_: NSTableView, viewFor: NSTableColumn?, row: Int)` you need to look up one of the `User` objects you fetched, and then use that `User` info in the table cell. The `row` argument tells you which one to get from the array. You would use a line that's *something like* this to get the right `User`:

```
guard let currentUser = self.items[row] else { return nil }
```

Again, maybe you need to use `users` instead of `items`, depending how you resolve the conflict between those.

Now you can get `currentUser.firstName` and `currentUser.lastName` and use those in the table cell.